# If ptr is a pointer,what's the difference between typedef ptr p and typedef struct ptr p?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

update: thanx for your help!It's my mistake. I see the code from"Data structures and Algorithm Analysis:in c" but I misunderstood it, I tried and the code reported errors,so maybe I am not using it correctly. Maybe the code is just sth like Exmaple. I found the code in later pages and it is what I thought to be.The problem is solved.

-----------original question:
what's the difference between:

```
typedef struct node *ptr;
typedef struct ptr tree;
```

and:

```
typedef ptr tree?
```

we can use the second one to create a list, can we define a B-tree in this way?

if not, what's the difference?
(thanks)

Comment: As `ptr` is not defined as a struct, first is simply a syntax error. Do you need any other precision?

Comment: `typedef struct ptr tree;` should give an error. `typedef ptr tree;` shouldn't.

Comment: it is normally a bad idea to typedef pointers e.g. when you do a const on them you may get unexpected results.

Comment: In C++, the first doesn't compile at all. In C, `struct ptr` is not the same type as `ptr`, so it doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this as C? Because it doesn't make much sense as a C++ question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't really have to write the word `struct` if `node` is already defined, so the following is fine:

```
struct node
{
};

typedef node *nptr; //same result as typedef struct node *nptr;

nptr nodePointer = new node();
```

However, you can use the `typedef struct` syntax as follows:

```
typedef struct {int first; int second;} S, *sPtr;
sPtr pointerToS; //same as S * pointerToS
```

Now, in your example you have

```
typedef struct node *ptr;
typedef struct ptr tree;
```

The first line means that `ptr` now means `a pointer to node`. The second line basically says "please call the *ptr* structure a *tree* from now on". However, `ptr` is a pointer to `node`, not a `struct`, that's why you will get an error similar to `using typedef-name 'ptr' after 'struct'`.

The line

```
typedef ptr tree;
```

on the other hand, says "please call *ptr* a *tree* from now on", no matter what `ptr` is, so it compiles fine.